# Can I do a 301 on a mod rewrited url with no extension?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am running a site that has mod rewrites running on it I am running into a issue when I delete or archive a product. All my rewrites, rewrite to file names without extensions

I want to re-driect that old page to a new page or the archived product page.

Now since there is no .html or .php extention on the link when I do a mod rewrite it gives me some funny stuff happening in the url.

Redirect 301 /products/tuners/C422-Tuner/reviews http://nadelectronics.com/products/tuners/C425-Tuner/reviews

Gives an old url with a question mark differentiating the two. but if you use a 301 on a file that has an extension you get a proper re-direct

so my question is... can I do a 301 on a mod rewrited url with no extension?

Answer (score 0):

The extensions should not make any difference at all.

Note also that you're not using mod_rewrite. The 'Redirect' directive is part of mod_alias, which is considerably more limited in what it can do. Perhaps it'd be helpful to read up on [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).